# Use extern c++ dll in Unity3D 5

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unity-game-engine

I wrote a C++ dll which I want to use in Unity3D. I put it into Assets/Plugins and wrote a C# script which should access a function of it but I get this error:

EntryPointNotFoundException: Multiply
test.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/test.cs:11)
Manager.h:

```
extern "C"
{
    class Manager
    {
    public:
        __declspec(dllexport) float Multiply(float a, float b);
    };
}
```

Manager.cpp:

```
 #include "Manager.h" 

extern "C"
{
    float Manager::Multiply(float a, float b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

C# script:

```
 [DllImport("Manager", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern float Multiply(float a, float b);

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(Multiply(10, 2));
    }
```

Edit: This doesn't work during I'm using a class. To use a class you have to do it like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/49304/creating-an-instance-of-a-c-plugin.html)

Comment: Just a minor thing, why are you `__declspec(dllimport)` a function you want to `dllexport`? And that `Multiply` functions is inside a class and declared `public`, so wouldn't that require an object instance of a `Manager` object? (maybe try following the conventions from a tutorial like http://unreferencedinstance.com/tutorial_cpp_unity3d/ or http://ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged)

Comment: You are right, the "class Manager" was the problem. Is there a way how can I use this with a class?

Comment: Classes and DLLs are really tricky. The reason most people use an "extern C" when dealing with DLL boundaries is that compilers perform "name-mangling" on C++ functions/classes and it is inconsistent from compiler to compiler, as well as version to version within the same compiler. For a few implementation options check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: In C#, you need to create a struct that represents the Manager class, and in C++ you need to provide a C wrapper API; functions that can be used to instantiate the C++ Manager instance, and invoke Multiply on a Manager instance.  Then in C# you DLLImport the C wrapper API and use the C# struct for Manager as the transient object from C# to C++.